React Native Webview - Sign in with Google
we have developed web application, but in the development time we have found out that we will need to release this as native mobile application. So we have decided to finish web app development - where we also had all social register/login methods (Google, Apple, Meta) and then put this application into webview (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md).
When we tried access Google Oauth client for web from for example iOS application - we got the error 403 disallowed_useragent from google OAuth. So what came into my mind - we can pass client ID (that we create for separate native android and iOS application) to web app and use appropriate client ID. We have managed to avoid the error with useragent but now we are getting error: 400 redirect_uri_mismatch. Is there any way to implement Google login with Webview? Because on some threads I have read that it simply is not possible.

I have had a similar problem with our web-based react-native app. To solve this we had to implement OAuth on the react-native side using https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth and promoting the result to the web part via JS injection. Perhaps this could work for you as well.

Yeah I think this is the easiest way from what I have seen so far. Implementing Login and Registration in Native Layer. Thank you

Add a userAgent in to Webview
<WebView
    source={{uri: params?.uri}}
    onLoad={() => setIsLoading(false)}
    onLoadEnd={() => setIsLoading(false)}
    onError={() => setIsLoading(false)}
    userAgent={CHROME_USER_AGENT} //Here

